# How to modify built in LAPACK routine in Intel MKL

Tags: lapack, intel-mkl

I am using a C++ code that uses intel MKL LAPACK functions. I have a problem with one of the functions(same as https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/299717) and it is suggested modifying this function to solve the problem. I know how to modify this function in the LAPACK source but I don't know how to modify it in intel MKL LAPACK. Is it possible to modify intel MKL LAPACK and how?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible to modify this issue in MKL LAPACK. You may only take one of the latest versions of this library from this page: https://software.seek.intel.com/performance-libraries. It is for free.